# Elasticsearch - aggregate by columns

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

Is there any possibility to split one column into a few separate fields? 
For instance, I have some column with integer values and I want to create a few fields based on this column:

```
1. 0-10
2. 11-20
3. 21-
```

Furthermore, I want to count records in each above column that occurs for each daily date.

That's the way it should be:

```
  date     | 0-10 | 11-20 | 21-
-------------------------------
2016-10-04 | 5    | 10    | 20
2016-10-05 | 7    | 15    | 33
...
```

I was trying to do this using both Kibana and Jasper Report tool with elasticsearch plugin and I only got something like this:

```
    date   | range | count
---------------------------
2016-10-04 | 0-10  | 5
2016-10-04 | 11-20 | 10 
2016-10-04 | 21-   | 20
2016-10-05 | 0-10  | 7
2016-10-05 | 11-20 | 15
2016-10-05 | 21-   | 33
```

**Edited**
I was trying this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "*",
          "analyze_wildcard": true
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "dateTime": {
                  "gte": 1445074439703,
                  "lte": 1476696839703,
                  "format": "epoch_millis"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "dateTime",
        "interval": "1d",
        "time_zone": "Europe/Berlin",
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": 1445074439703,
          "max": 1476696839703
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "3": {
          "range": {
            "field": "milisecElapsed",
            "ranges": [
              {
                "from": 0,
                "to": 200
              },
              {
                "from": 200,
                "to": 990
              },
              {
                "from": 990
              },
              {
                "from": 200
              },
              {
                "from": 0
              }
            ],
            "keyed": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do this using Kibana, or programmatically, using ElasticSearch's query DSL?

Comment: Actually, It doesn't matter - both solutions would be good because at the end of the day I want to create a pdf report. If I can do this using Kibana it would be great but I can also use Jasper Report with Elasticsearch query DSL.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the Elasticsearch documentation for [Date Histogram Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) and [Range Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html), I think you can nest the range aggregations inside the daily histogram. Something like this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "by_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field":     "date",
        "interval":  "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "integer_ranges": {
          "range": {
            "field": "your_integer_column_name"
            "ranges": [
              { "to": 10,
              { "from": 11, "to": 20 }
              { "from": 21 }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This should return a list of days with nested document count for the specified ranges.

Since I don't know the name of your integer attribute name, you'll need to replace the `your_integer_column_name` with the ES attribute inside your document.

Hopefully, there aren't any missing parentheses.

Let me know if this gets you closer to what you were thinking of :)

Comment: Thank you Mihai for the answer. Unfortunately, this is not what I'm looking for. I was trying use something like this before but I got values in one column... Please, see edited question.

Comment: By accident, I edited your post but now is everything ok - sorry for that.

Comment: Mihai Ionescu any ideas? Each hint could be helpful :)